Raspberry CM4 UART with anticipative RTS signal
I am using RPi CM4 with UART for a project. This is the relevant part of /boot/config.txt:
#-------Serial/UART-----
# NB: "enable_uart=1" will enforce "core_freq=250" on RPi models with onboard WiFi.
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=disable-bt
gpio=14=a0
gpio=15=a0,pu
gpio=17=a3
gpio=16=a3

If relevant, my /boot/cmdline.txtis:
root=PARTUUID=df909cde-02 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fsck.repair=yes net.ifnames=0 logo.nologo console=tty1

The UART is working and transmitting the expected data, however the RTS signal (blue, see picture) appears to anticipate a little the TX signal (red). We are talking about 0.1 ms (scale missing in picture).

Since I am using the RTS pin to enable a RS485 transceiver, this causes an unwanted initial spike on the signal and the data (Modbus) is not interpreted correctly on the receiver.
Needless to say, I've tried different configurations so far, with no luck.
Is there a way to set a delay via software? I am using DietPi distro, but ready to switch if needed.
EDIT
More hardware info. I am using a LTC2854IDD transceiver. Here the pins from the datasheet.

TX (pin 14) is connected to DI.
RX (pin 15) is connected to RO with a 100k pull-up.
RTS (pin 17) is connected to both DE and /RE pins.
CTS (pin 16) is unconnected.
TE is connected to 3V3 (terminator resistor enabled).
Nothing else. What may be causing this glitch?
I think the problem resides more into the CM4 than the transceiver.
EDIT2:
Posting the image of RS485 lines A (blue) and B (red) after the transceiver.


RTS is supposed to anticipate TXD. You should instead be focusing on why turning the driver on when the bus is idle is causing a "spike", and also why this "spike" is confusing the receiver. Neither of these should be happening.

With RS-485, you are supposed to enable the transmitter with RTS before transmitting data, and this will happen without any glitches. So if you have glitches, you have a problem, maybe your hardware design is incorrect. Please provide more info to solve this.

@DaveTweed If RTS is supposed to anticipate, wouldn't this amount of time depend on the transceiver response time?

The RS485 should be biased so that undriven it is in the idle state. It also depends on the transceivers used - 75176 doesn’t like unbiased buses whereas a MAX485 will default the receiver to the idle state on an undriven bus. There’s a NS/TI document “10 ways to bulletproof RS485” or suchlike. Read this.

The glitch is caused by not making the hardware or the bus according to best practices. Generally all RS-485 devices should consider the bus idle when nobody drives it. It seems your device does not implement bus "fail-safe" biasing for the idle condition, and some slave device does not like that situation.
ModBus calls this "Line Polarization", and each device must document if it needs polarization or if it can provide polarization.
Of course there may be a grounding issue between devies. Many people think RS-485 is a two-wire interface but it isn't, the devices must share a common ground reference too.
The mention terminating the other end of wire is missing as well. There must be terminations at both ends of the cable, which means, only two terminations, none in the middle.
So no, the problem is defnitely not about RPI4, and technically not about the RS485 transceiver chip either, but between the transceiver and bus.

Thank you. Termination are on both sides. I am testing only with one slave at the moment.

You put me on the right track. Turns out the issue was entirely caused by an unshielded cable. Replaced it and everything working as expected.

@decadenza OK but I don't think simply replacing the cable with shielded should have fixed it. Maybe you did something else too, like connected the shield to grounds on both devices.

I did nothing more. I've found out that the slave transceiver was always interpreting the noise on the line as logic 0 (noise was pretty constant - about 1V of voltage difference - when both transceivers were in receiver mode). Since RTS is enabled a few ns earlier, the "fake" 0 passed through as a wrong start bit and Modbus library could not decode the package.
